# How does Spring boot and Postgres handle the concurrent updates?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, postgres, spring-boot

I want to understand how does Spring Boot and Postgresql DB handle the concurrent requests for updating a value in DB. Consider this example of facebook likes, if there are multiple instances of application running and each of them are getting multiple requests concurrently for a like on post, currently the like is only 1, and when all the request update the like at same time, the like count might not be the correct count, it might be less because of concurrent updates. So to solve this problem, we have locks, Do we need to handle the locking in spring boot only or DB do it for us, if DB does this, then why do we even have @Lock annotation in spring boot. Also, if locks are implements, then there might be so many requests waiting in queue in this process will eventually become Synchronous or Blocking which will makes the application slower and if the number of cores are less then after a point of time, no new thread will be left to handle other tasks since all might be waiting in queue to complete the like update operation in DB.

How do we deal with such problem of Concurrency and DB update? Correct me if I m wrong anywhere in the explanation anywhere. Thanks

Comment: Do you understand what a transaction is in SQL terms?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Yes I know, and that's why I have asked if the DB handles it then how do we scale our application for handling concurrent requests since using transactions will make it synchronous, and eventually slow, right?

Comment: Transactions do not make things synchronous unless they are updating the same data. They are _not_ locks (at least not in the naive sense).

Comment: Not necessarily. There are many factors that affect application performance. Database locks can cause things to slow down, but not because a SQL database is involved. Because you are locking tables. It might be a good idea to research ways to accomplish concurrent updates in a SQL database without the need for locks.

Comment: One possible way that can help minimize "visible" performance hindrance, is to do these kinds of updates asynchronously, as in, out of the request-response cycle. A user would click the "upvote" button, the server, instead of trying to increment the counter, would store the command in a queue, and immediately return a successful response. In the background, a component would poll the queue, and perform the updates, eventually achieving consistency without halting the user.